# Pycharm autocomplete pytest

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

Is it possible to enable pytest autocompletion in PyCharm 2.7.3?

The problem is that pytest.py looks like this:

```
...
# we are simply imported
from _pytest.core import main, UsageError, _preloadplugins
from _pytest import core as cmdline
from _pytest import __version__
_preloadplugins() # to populate pytest.* namespace so help(pytest) works
```

So there are only `main`, `cmdline` and `UsageError` in autocompletion list.

I suppose, PyCharm can't look into `_preloadplugins()`.

Are there any ways to tell it to do that? For example, to execute modules that are imported and then collect `globals()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug for autocomplete for protected methods and variables. Please vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10745 to get it fixed and receive updates on this issue.

Comment: He is talking about general completion, not only the protected members.